# Asynchronous Operation in Realm-Xamarin

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin, realm

I am learning Realm in Xamarin.

I am trying to insert some sample data by using `Thread`. I don't face any issue, until I call the same function in multiple threads. The realm document says to perform insert operations inside `executeTransactionAsync` , but I don't see any methods like that in Realm-Xamarin.

Here is the code.

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread(() => TestThread.CountTo10("Thread 1"));
thread1.Start();

Thread thread2 = new Thread(() => TestThread.CountTo10("Thread 2"));
thread2.Start();
```

**Thread class:**

```
public class TestThread
{
    public static Realm realm;
    public static void CountTo10(string _threadName)
    {
        realm = Realm.GetInstance();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            realm.Write(() =>
            {
                RandomNumber random = new RandomNumber();
                System.Console.WriteLine("Iteration: " + i.ToString() + " Random No: " + random.number.ToString() + " from " + _threadName);
                realm.Manage(random);
            });

            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }
}
```

**Realm Object:**

```
public class RandomNumber : RealmObject
{
    public int number { get; set; }

    public RandomNumber()
    {
        number = (new Random()).Next();
    }
}
```

Comment: The xamarin docs: https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/latest/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `realm` variable is `static`, and this will eventually result in illegal thread access. Just remove `static` and you'll be good to go:

```
public class TestThread
{
    public void CountTo10(string _threadName)
    {
        Realm realm = Realm.GetInstance();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            realm.Write(() =>
            {
                RandomNumber random = new RandomNumber();
                System.Console.WriteLine("Iteration: " + i.ToString() + " Random No: " + random.number.ToString() + " from " + _threadName);
                realm.Manage(random);
            });

            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
        // no need to call `Realm.close()` in Realm-Xamarin, that closes ALL instances.
        // Realm instance auto-closes after this line
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But is this code thread safe? I mean, I use the same realm object (the default one) to write. I just tried with 10000 records in 5 async. thread and I didn't get any crash. But I want to confirm that.

Comment: I was expecting some answer which uses the alternative of executeTransactionAsync method like in the document.

Comment: Realm is thread-local. When you say `Realm.getInstance()`, you use the default configuration to open a new Realm instance for that given thread. When you say `.Write(() -> {...`, that call is blocking across threads, so only one thread can *write* at a given moment in time. And because all managed RealmObjects (and Realm instances) are thread-confined, as a result of this, *they are by definition also thread-safe*: they cannot be read nor modified from other threads.

Comment: Got it, Thank you.